# Royal Canin Feline Urinary SO vs. Purina Pro Plan Urinary Tract Health

Tags: cats, diet, urination

My cat has been on Royal Canin Feline Urinary SO dry food for a couple of years. However recently Royal Canin changed the formula for that food and it is making cats puke. All reviews starting January 2020 have pet owners reporting this problem.

I came across "Purina Pro Plan Focus Urinary Tract Health Formula Adult Dry Cat Food" which does not require a prescription. I would like to know if it is comparable to Royal Canin Urinary SO and if it can be safely substituted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot make medical recommendations, since I am not a vet, but as pet-owner during COVID-19 pandemic lockdown I suggest you call your vet's office. I was able to get a routine prescription over the telephone from my vet. My cat had been seen at the clinic last fall. Since he is still growing, I had to weigh him on the bathroom scales so the vet could prescribe the right doze. Another time, I called for medical advice that the person at the front desk was able to answer.

All this makes me think it might be worth giving your vet's office a call to ask for advice, since the vet seems to know your cat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sarah. It's been over a year since our last vet visit, and our vet refused to approve any new food or give recommendations over the phone without an in person appointment and a urine PH test. Obviously with the current COVID-19 situation any in person appointment is out of the question.

Comment: I am so sorry for your situation. The only other thing I can think of is to talk to the people who make the pet food.